# robots.txt communication in webmining

Tags: data-mining, nlp

I hope this is the right subforum as I did not really find a suiting one.
I'm mining data from a website that does specifically exclude some crawlers from it's site in the robots.txt like this:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow:
User-agent: Proxetrics2000
Disallow: /
```

While I'm pretty sure I'm not Proxetrics2000, how can I know which User-Agent to comply to?  Let's say I'm mining too frequently and the admin wants to restrict me from certain sites. He would want to add my name to

```
User-Agents: dnns
Disallow: /
```

Is there a way to tell the website "a name" of my crawler? I'm looking forward to your answers. To me this seems an oddly obvious questions, however I did not find anything while searching for it.

Cheers,

Dennis